# Can't install Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: installation

I have tried to instll ubuntu on my old laptop running win 7 for a week now, but all of my attepts have been unsuccessful so far. I have never used it before so it is very new to me. 
I have burned 2 discs with different isos and both didn't even get to the installer. First time i saw the installer was with unetbootin and the it showed some error about my cdrom not being able to unmount. I even bought a 4gb usb to install with livelinux and that gave me the same error. My old laptop has an intel 945 motherboard. Please help.

Comment: Can you edit your question specifying what kind of laptop it is?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the standard USB installation instructions mentioned on the Ubuntu website?
If that doesn't work on your laptop. Try it on any other machine you have access to. That could help determine whether the problem is with your laptop or the installation media.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the laptop is not very compatible with 11.10, because the unity interface and some of its background apps take a lot of memory and cpu usage that the whole hardware could be slowed down and not able to even load up live cd, which in this case cds and usb sticks are useless. The only thing to the solution, i would recommend to install 10.04 and go with that. If you research for how to upgrade to the software that is on the 11.10, i can assure u that u will go fine with 10.04.

Comment: How can you assume that his laptop is not compatible if you don't know what kind it is?